# Add extra form on woo-commerce My Account Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

woocomerce give the short code [woocommerce_my_account]. which gives "Billing Address" and "Shipping Address" form in 'My Account' Page.

I want to add some extra form Like "Add product" with same structure and functionality like "Shipping Address" and "Billing Address" with my custom field .

Because i want to add a "product Entry" form with this page from front-end.

How it will be possible . Is there any hook or something which allow me to add custom form. Please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

M providing you with steps that you can follow to achieve your goal. But you will need to code the intermediate stuff on your own.

1. create a php file for you form and place it inside the myaccount
   folder in woocommerce templates folder.
2. add a hidden field in your form with a specific name, for ex: name="my-custom-field".
3. Dont provide any "action" attribute to that form.
4. include your template in my-account.php file : `woocommerce_get_template( 'myaccount/my-custom-form.php' );`
5. on `init` hook, check if your `my-custom-field` is available. `if(isset($_REQUEST['my-custom-field']))`.
6. If available, create a new product entry with the values provided in the form.

for creating product :

```
wp_insert_post ( array (
                            'post_type'    => 'product' ,
                            'post_title'   => '' ,
                            'post_name'    => '' ,
                            'post_author'  => '' ,
                            'post_content' => '' ,
                            'post_status'  => ''
                        ) ) ;
```